# HEVC Deblocking filter algorithm

Tags: video-processing, video-compression

I'm doing research on block noise caused by video compression (especially in newer codecs) and I've read the IEEE article about the HEVC deblocking filter ([here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6324414)).

However, when reading the algorithm I'm confused because the formula seems wrong. The first formula to determine if the deblocking filter will affect a block is:

$ |p_2,_0 - 2p_1,_0+p_0,_0|+|p_2,_3 - 2p_1,_3+p_0,_3|+|q_2,_0 - 2q_1,_0+q_0,_0|+|q_2,_3 - 2q_1,_3+q_0,_3|>\beta \ (1)$

It is also written (and shown in a figure) that $\beta $ increases with the quantification parameter QP.

Moreover, later it is written that to choose between normal and strong deblocking, the following equation is used (with $i$ going from $0$ to $3$):

$ |p_2,_i - 2p_1,_i+p_0,_i|+|q_2,_i - 2q_1,_i+q_0,_i|<\beta/8 \ (2) $

Since IEEE is a respectable source and the paper is a couple years old, it would surprise me that there is a typo. However, I do not understand how this formula can work. It does seem to me that the second inequation would always be wrong at least for some $i$ if the first one is true.

Am I misunderstanding how the filter works or is it a typo in the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ffmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) implementation of the HEVC decoding follows this formula instead:

$ |p_2,_0 - 2p_1,_0+p_0,_0|+|p_2,_3 - 2p_1,_3+p_0,_3|+|q_2,_0 - 2q_1,_0+q_0,_0|+|q_2,_3 - 2q_1,_3+q_0,_3|<\beta \ (1)$

This appears in the [hevc_deblock.asm](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/x86/hevc_deblock.asm) file.

```
;compare
    pcmpgtw         m15, m13, m14
    movmskps        r13, m15 ;filtering mask 0d0 + 0d3 < beta0 (bit 2 or 3) , 1d0 + 1d3 < beta1 (bit 0 or 1)
    test            r13, r13
    je              .bypassluma
```

So I conclude that there is a mistake in the paper and the correct formula is that one (since it also makes more sense).

edit: As the comment suggested, I checked in the reference implementation for the algorithm and the interesting part is here in the file [TComLoopFilter.cpp](https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/trunk/source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComLoopFilter.cpp):

```
for (UInt iBlkIdx = 0; iBlkIdx<uiBlocksInPart; iBlkIdx ++)
      {
        Int dp0 = xCalcDP( piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+0), iOffset);
        Int dq0 = xCalcDQ( piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+0), iOffset);
        Int dp3 = xCalcDP( piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+3), iOffset);
        Int dq3 = xCalcDQ( piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+3), iOffset);
        Int d0 = dp0 + dq0;
        Int d3 = dp3 + dq3;

        Int dp = dp0 + dp3;
        Int dq = dq0 + dq3;
        Int d =  d0 + d3;

//...

        if (d < iBeta) //<-not a >Beta as the paper said
        {
          Bool bFilterP = (dp < iSideThreshold);
          Bool bFilterQ = (dq < iSideThreshold);

          Bool sw =  xUseStrongFiltering( iOffset, 2*d0, iBeta, iTc, piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+0))
          && xUseStrongFiltering( iOffset, 2*d3, iBeta, iTc, piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+3));

          for ( Int i = 0; i < DEBLOCK_SMALLEST_BLOCK/2; i++)
          {
            xPelFilterLuma( piTmpSrc+iSrcStep*(iIdx*uiPelsInPart+iBlkIdx*4+i), iOffset, iTc, sw, bPartPNoFilter, bPartQNoFilter, iThrCut, bFilterP, bFilterQ, bitDepthLuma);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! +1 for your question as well as answer for adding to an important subject. However, I wish you could find a bit more sources from published work be it tutorials, or may be the standard itself than a code like ffmpeg itself. You should always take software implementation by pinch of salt.

Comment: Well I have also looked into the reference implementation so I added it as well. I don't have access to the standard specification (since my university doesn't have access and my lab would rather avoid spending the money if I don't really need it) so that's the only other source I could get.